# Как правильно написать формулировку

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно пишется: "Вынести вопрос на утверждение Правлением Общества" или "Вынести вопрос на утверждение Правлению Общества"? Какое правило русского языка применимо?

Comment: Правил тут нет, поскольку "вынести" - кому, "утвердить" - кем. Выбирайте, чистая стилистика. Хотя мне ваш первый вариант ("утверждение Правлением Общества" ближе. Вот только аж две заглавные тут плохо смотрятся...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден самостоятельно. В контексте формулировки подразумевается придание законной силы (документу) коллегиальным органом, соответственно, формулировка "Правлению Общества" или, как часто встречающийся вариант, "Правления Общества", не является правильной. Большое спасибо всем участникам!

Answer (score 0):

*Первый* вариант грамматически возможен (утверждение чего-то теми-то), но не совсем понятно, что такое "утверждение *вопроса*", который вместо его рассмотрения куда-то выносят: это разрешающее утверждение к рассмотрению?

Ко *второму* варианту возникает такой вопрос: что можно "вынести" *кому*-либо? Кроме выговора или благодарности (с их вариациями) трудно что-либо предложить, а с "вопросом" "вынесение кому-то" явно *не* сочетается.

Предлагаемый вариант:

> Представить вопрос Правлению Общества для утверждения (вынесенного
>   решения).

Comment: В вопросе не спрашивается, какой вариант грамматически ВОЗМОЖЕН, спрашивается, какой вариант является правильным. Сама формулировка, к сожалению, корректировке не подлежит, поскольку вопрос рассмотрен одним коллегиальным органом и передается на утверждение другому коллегиальному органу.